# Issues with react-big-calender

Tags: html, css, reactjs, calendar, react-big-calendar

I'm working with calenders for the first time in react and found react-big-calender interesting. I've created the calender with some events but I'm experiencing some console errors which I'm not familiar with.

```
Warning: Using UNSAFE_componentWillReceiveProps in strict mode is not recommended and may indicate 
bugs in your code. 

* Move data fetching code or side effects to componentDidUpdate. 
* If you're updating state whenever props change, refactor your code to use memoization techniques or 
  move it to static getDerivedStateFromProps.

Please update the following components: DayColumn, TimeGrid, TimeGutter
```

Can someone explain this to me? Thank you!

Also, I would like to know if its possible to only display month view and not all (day,week,agenda) views.

Here is my code :

```
   render(){

    const localizer = momentLocalizer(moment)

    const holidays = []  

    this.state.holidays.map((holiday,index) => {

        let start = moment(holiday.for_date).toDate()
        holidays.push({ start: start, 
                        end: start, 
                        color: holiday.color, 
                        key:index, 
                        title:holiday.title})
        })

    const list = [...holidays]     

   return(
   <div className="calender">
     <Calendar
       localizer={localizer}
       events={list}
       defaultDate={moment().toDate()}
       startAccessor="start"
       endAccessor="end"
     />
  </div>
  )}
```

Answer (score 1):

In brief, what this means is that the maintainers of the NPM package, Big Calendar, have not yet updated their code to move away from deprecated features, specifically `componentWillReceiveProps`, in the case of this warning.

There's nothing you can do on your side in your app.

It does look like there is some progress, as can be seen [here](https://github.com/jquense/react-big-calendar/issues/1620).